# Getting color of a data series from a flot chart

Tags: jquery, flot

After seeing the cool new "reputation" tab on the stackoverflow user page, I was inspired to play with the Flot charting library a little.  I have a line chart that has several hundred series.  Only a couple of these series will be visible at any given time.  My data series are grouped into several "categories" and I assign the numeric color index based on that category.  I'd like to be able to see what actual color was assigned by Flot to a particular color index value, for the ultimate purpose of creating a custom legend that relates the color to my "category" of data.  How can I get these color values?

I see that I can provide my own array for colors, but I am reluctant to do this, because I am not sure how many categories I will have until I load the data.  I suppose I could just create an array that's just *way* too big, but that seems wasteful if it's possible to ask Flot what color each series is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an example at the bottom of http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt that does just that. Something like:

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options)
var series = plot.getData();
for (var i = 0; i < series.length; ++i)
   alert(series[i].color);
```

Comment: And I actually tried to read those docs... I guess I trailed off at the end!  Thanks!

Comment: How to determine specific series in `series`?

Comment: They'll be in the same order as they are in `data`.