# Getting RGB colors that flot auto-generates

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I’m looking for a way to get the RGB colors that flot auto-generates for series. Auto-generated colors, specified by their index, are important in my case as users are supposed to add and remove series and the total number of series is not fixed. I also intend to develop a custom legend indicating the series colors and one way to get them would be from the plotted series, i.e. `plot.getData()[i].color` (where i is the index) as Tom has shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173205/getting-color-of-a-data-series-from-a-flot-chart#answer-173226).

However, I would like to use the colors before creating the plot or before plotting any series on it. Is there a fixed correlation or a mapping function which returns the RGB color for a given index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default colors are (taken from the source code): `colors: ["#edc240", "#afd8f8", "#cb4b4b", "#4da74d", "#9440ed"]`. If you have more data series Flot will use lighter or darker versions of these colors, you could search the source code for the specific method.

Alternatively you can define a specific color for each data series which you then use for the legend and the plot (that's what I do in a similar situation).

Comment: I suspected that I have to dive into the source code or develop a color generator. It seems that there is no other way.